# Passing arguments into casperjs.start

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to pass multiple URLs from an array into the following example code.

```
casper.start('http://www.weather.com/', function() {
    this.captureSelector('weather.png', '#wx-main');
});

casper.run();
```

I would somehow like to create a for-loop to run through this section of code while replacing the URL to one stored within an array.

When I have tried to pass any arguments into it I just get errors.

My 'code':

```
links = [
    'http://www.cnn.com/',
    'http://www.weather.com/',
    'http://www.google.com/',
    'http://www.stackoverflow.com/'
    ]; //array of links
casper.echo(links.length +' included links.'); //total number of links in array

//begin for loop of urls
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

    casper.echo(links[i]);
    function captureurl(links[i]); 

}

function captureurl(cpurl){
casper.start(cpurl, function() {
this.captureSelector('capture/capture'+i+'.png', '#body');
});

casper.run();
}
```

the for loop is capable of listing the links, but throws errors whenever I try to pass any parameters into here: casper.start(cpurl, function() {

Appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Comment: I think you can only call .start once - you want .thenOpen

Comment: so for some reason I cant seem to pass any of my urls using the function arguments. Is there something obvious that I'm doing with regards to that? The loop will happily display all of the elements within the array `casper.echo(links[i]);` but the function just gives me nothing.

Comment: Okay! after quite a bit of tinkering I split out the function into two separate functions, with an if statement within the for loop which determines if its the first capture of the array (use .start) and then after that use .thenOpen. Its all working pretty well now although I've yet to test it on a larger array but I am hopeful that it will work! Thanks for the advice! as a total novice and slightly biting off more than I can chew with this project (the only way I ever keep interested and learn) your help has been great!

Comment: You can start without opening a page, then use .thenOpen for everything.

Comment: Thanks so much @nrabinowitz! Massive help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread, answers inside:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/Scx4Cjqp7hE/discussion

Another approach here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/bhA81OyHA7s